# Outlook recurring tasks repeating

Tags: microsoft-outlook, tasks

I like to use recurring tasks in outlook. I use the different notes each day in the tasks so I don't want the notes to carry over to the new regenerated tasks. How can I start each recurring tasks with the notes cleared.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. As you have found, Outlook basically copies the task when it regenerates it. So, there isn't a option to remove the notes. Something like that might be accomplished using VBA. Are you familiar with VBA?

Comment: Charlie RB, thanks but not familiar with it. Explain would you?

Comment: VBA is [Visual Basic for Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications). It is code language used to program automation and functions into applications which are not standard features. Unfortunately, it is not something which can be taught here. There are plenty of resources online to learn how to use VBA if you choose.